# GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74)

Tags: android, exception, gradle

I am in a class for mobile programming and working with Android Studio. For the final project I am making a text "chose your adventure" game. Everything was working until I added a second activity. Then MainActivity.java developed shows an R. cannot be resolved. Questions about this error have been covered several times in these forums and I have tried the solutions given to no avail. I then started going through the stack trace and trying solutions that were given. Also with no success. The last I looked up was this - "at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74)". It was recently asked, but with no answer. I was glad to see that is was a recent problem and that I was not the only one having it. The asker of the question was trying to accomplish something different than I was and was getting a different stack trace so I am hoping that someone will know what I am doing wrong. I do not wish any help in creating my app., just in figuring out why I can not get gradle to play nice with me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.ty

I have updated gradle, studio and android gradle plugin.

log
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:865)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar -M \?\C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Gargoyle\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Gargoyle\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release -m -J \?\C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Gargoyle\app\build\generated\source\r\release -F C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Gargoyle\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-release.ap_ --custom-package org.naturalattitude.gargoyle -0 apk --output-text-symbols \?\C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Gargoyle\app\build\intermediates\symbols\release --no-version-vectors}
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:60)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:47)
    ... 9 more

Message Gradle Build

Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateReleaseSources, :app:prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:compileReleaseSources, :app:compileReleaseUnitTestSources]
Error:String types not allowed (at 'fullBackupContent' with value 'Gargoyle').
Error:String types not allowed (at 'fullBackupContent' with value 'Gargoyle').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 13.485 secs
>   Information:3 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Gradle Console
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:865)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar -M \?\C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Gargoyle\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Gargoyle\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release -m -J \?\C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Gargoyle\app\build\generated\source\r\release -F C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Gargoyle\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-release.ap_ --custom-package org.naturalattitude.gargoyle -0 apk --output-text-symbols \?\C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Gargoyle\app\build\intermediates\symbols\release --no-version-vectors}
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:60)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:47)
    ... 9 more

Sorry for the reports in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything was working until I added a second activity. Then MainActivity.java developed shows an R. cannot be resolved.

I think this is the important symptom and any complaints from gradle or other build components are just cascading errors.

The `R.` namespace contains the visual resources, and when it is not available it means that something failed during compilation of the resouces (like a syntax error or missing end tag in the axml files). You need to figure out why resource compilation fails.

So you said adding a second activity triggered this. The first step should then be to back up to the state before adding this and verify that things work fine. Then you gradually add what you had in small steps to see where it breaks (e.g. add the new activity but comment out all its content. Then uncomment part by part).

If you have committed changes in smaller steps like you should (**you DO use a source control system, right?**), this should be relatively easily and if you are using git you can use the `git bisect` command.

Comment: Yes, I use source control and Git. I will try the git bisect. Thank you

Comment: Hello again. Ty, I backed up and found that if I commented out the following -  //  setContentView(org.naturalattitude.gargoyle.R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}

Comment: Hello again. Ty, I backed up and found that if I commented out the following -  //  setContentView(org.naturalattitude.gargoyle.R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}                After taking that out the main error was gone and I am back to an error that I am sure has a simple fix, but again I have tried the earlier suggested and the do not work. The drawable file in resource is not being found. The whole resource is not found -     Error:(12, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/gargoyle.png'). This is in the build/intermediate file.

Comment: I have checked the checked the files in question. The ones in -C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\GargoyleTest\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\  - and they are all there, but not being found. Anyone have any idea why this would be? They are  exactly where Studio reports not finding them. Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is the 3rd and final error - Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt